# I want redirect 301 redirection

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess

I have two url ,I want redirect old url to new url but its not working.
any help.this is not working in .htaccess file any help through php

```
Redirect 301 /online/student-login?task=user.login 

http://dev.example.com/devplopment/online/student-login?user.login
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. *What* isn't working? You haven't shown any code (or in this case, your redirection rules, aside from one line, without any context). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: David Makogon@sorry its was a mistake.right now  I have updated .I want redirect a old url to new url ,please help

Comment: The Redirect directive matches on the URL _path_ only. You need to use mod_rewrite if you want to specifically check the contents of the query string (RewriteCond), and then use a RewriteRule to perform the redirect.

Comment: Amin Adel@any example

Answer (score 1):

you need to use php like this :

```
<?php 
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: http://www.example.com/new-page.html"); 
?>
```

301 redirect can not be done with javascript. because it is client side and not effective.

if you want to use htaccess. add this lines to your htacces file :

```
Redirect 301 /old-page.html http://www.example.com/new-page.html
```

Comment: Amin Adel@Ima using this code in index.php but this code does not working

Comment: Amin Adel@i have used this .htaccess rule but this does not work

Comment: these codes are correct, if they don't work, the problem  must be other place. check if php runs or not. run phpinfo() at first line of the php file. to see server configs. and ask another question if there is a problem.